# Bash Script to Pass String to Matlab

Tags: string, bash, matlab

I am trying to write a bash script to pass a user input string into a Matlab function.

This is the script I currently have:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Input a message.
read message
matlab -r -nosplash -nodesktop -nojvm "arduinoWriter\(\'$message\'\);"
```

where arduinoWriter is a Matlab function that takes a string as an input.

If I run the script and input `HELLO` , it works as expected. If however I input  `HELLO WORLD`, it does not work. Something about the space is messing it up.

If I run the command `matlab -r -nosplash -nodesktop -nojvm "arduinoWriter\(\HELLO\ WORLD\'\);"` in the terminal, it works fine, but not if I use `HELLO\ WORLD` as in the input to the bash script. Even if it did work as an input, I would prefer not to have to put slashes in front of every space.

Any ideas?

Comment: As alternatives, you could use `input` within MATLAB, or write an M-file script that you execute with `matlab -r`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is that you separate the `-r` parameter and its argument. You need to reorder your command line so that `-r` appears after the other arguments, and right before the command to execute:

```
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -nojvm -r command
```

(Actually, the order of parameters doesn't matter, but you need to keep `-r command` together.)

Next, within the double quotes, you [don't need to escape the parenthesis or the single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html):

> Enclosing characters in double quotes (`"`) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of `$`, `` ` ``, `\`, and, when history expansion is enabled, `!`.

Thus, removing all the backslashes from your command, we get:

```
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -nojvm -r "disp('$message');"
```

(I replaced your function call with something that would actually work on my machine, for testing.)

Comment: Works perfectly now. Thank you!